# Azure | Ubuntu Machine vs Windows10 Machine Costing

Tags: azure, devops, virtual

I have noticed that costing per hour for Ubuntu Machine is same as Windows 10 Machine of same VM type.

For Example

1. If we take 1st VM as
   Machine Type : A8v2
   Image : Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
   Cost/hr : 27.5621 INR
2. If we take 2nd Machine with same spec but with windows 10 (pro 1809) AMI
   Machine Type : A8v2
   Image : Windows 10 Pro 1809
   Cost 27.5621 INR

As you can see both machines are costing same. Does Azure not charge of Windows 10 Activation or is there any hidden fees.

Comment: Windows licensing cost is included in the hourly rate.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably using a Dev/Test subscription.  In a Dev/Test sub, there is no extra change for Windows Server or for Windows 10; you just pay the core compute rates (eg, same rate as Linux.)
Note that you are not permitted to use a Dev/Test subscription for production workloads; they are exclusively for development and testing.  (And, there is no financially backed SLA on these subscriptions.)

See https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/offers/ms-azr-0023p/

Comment: Thanks , But It look like I have subscription based plan from Azure and still no extra cost for activated windows 10 is incurred.

Comment: Are you sure it's a standard pay as you go subscription and not a pay as you go dev/test sub?    Subscription offer types are outlined here:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/legal/offer-details/

Comment: Specifically, Windows 10 can only be deployed on a dev/test or Visual Studio Subscription per https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/client-images
"Active Visual Studio subscribers (people who have acquired a Visual Studio subscription license) can use Windows client for development and testing purposes. Windows client can be used on your own hardware and Azure virtual machines running in any type of Azure subscription. Windows client may not be deployed to or used on Azure for normal production use, or used by people who are not active Visual Studio subscribers."

Comment: The exception to this is if you have an enterprise E3/E5 license; then you can deploy Windows 10 to Azure in a standard subscription:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/windows-desktop-multitenant-hosting-deployment

Answer (score 0):

You must agree on "I confirm I have an eligible Windows 10/11 license with multi-tenant hosting rights."
That means you have to have windows license.
The windows license fees occurred.